# InterpolationControlSource with Gst.parse_launch()

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

My app (in Python), loads the Gstreamer library, parses and launches a pipeline spec that composites subtitles from an SRT file on top of a prepared video from an MP4 file, then creates a control source with a binding to the 'alpha' property of the sink pad of the *videomixer* element that is linked to the subtitle image source.

First I wrote a small [proof-of-concept](https://gist.github.com/lsiden/c66ed5f35a00657c9225d1dc04f07b0c) which works like a champ.  If you can run it with an X-windows server (in Unix or Linux for example), you will see a black square on a green background.  After a second, the black square gradually fades out over several seconds.

My app has a pipeline that is a bit more complex.  Below is a summary of the relevant code:

```
pipeline_spec = '''
videomixer name=mixer ! ... other stuff downstream
filesrc location=sample_videos/my-video.mp4 ! decodebin name=demuxer ! mixer.sink_0
filesrc location=subtitles.srt ! subparse ! textrender ! mixer.sink_1
demuxer. ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! faac ! muxer.
'''

self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_spec)
mixer = self.pipeline.get_by_name('mixer')
#vidpad = mixer.get_static_pad('sink_0')
srtpad = mixer.get_static_pad('sink_1')
self.logger.debug([ pad.name for pad in mixer.pads ])

cs = GstController.InterpolationControlSource()
cs.set_property('mode', GstController.InterpolationMode.LINEAR)
binding = GstController.DirectControlBinding.new(srtpad, 'alpha', cs)
cs.add_control_binding(binding)

with open(srtfilepath) as srtfile:
    for timestamps in parsesrt.parse(srtfile):
        start, end = timestamps
        self._set_subtitle_fade(alpha_cs, start, end)

def _set_fade_effect(self, controlsource, start, duration, alpha_begin, alpha_end):
    controlsource.set(start, alpha_begin)
    controlsource.set(start + duration, alpha_end)
    self.logger.debug('set fade-{0} from {1} to {2}'.format('in' if alpha_begin < alpha_end else 'out', start, start + duration))

def _set_subtitle_fade(self, controlsource, start_subtitle, end_subtitle):
    self._set_fade_effect(controlsource, start_subtitle, self.DURATION_FADEIN, 0, 1)
    self._set_fade_effect(controlsource, end_subtitle - self.DURATION_FADEOUT, self.DURATION_FADEOUT, 1, 0)
```

One difference between the two pipelines is that in the first example, the videomixer pads are *request* pads.  But in the real app, they turn out to be *static* pads.  And only 'sink_1' is present in the log statement.

```
DEBUG, ['src', 'sink_1']
```

I'm not sure why this is so or whether it makes a difference.

When I run the app in a web server and check in a browser, the subtitles appear but they do not fade in or out.

I checked the timestamps and they look good.  They are in nanoseconds (10^9).

```
set fade-in from 2440000000 to 3440000000
set fade-out from 2375000000 to 4375000000
set fade-in from 7476000000 to 8476000000
...
```

So what stone have I left unturned?

Answer (score 0):

The other big difference between your first and second prototypes is  `videotestsrc` changing to `filesrc ! decodebin`.  `gst_parse_launch` won't immediately connect `decodebin` to `videomixer`.  What'll happen is this:

- Pipeline is parsed but decodebin doesn't know the contents of filesrc until it de-muxes it.  It could be audio or a Powerpoint presentation or a PGP signature or anything.  So it returns no src pads initially.
- You play the pipeline.  `decodebin` begins receiving data from filesrc, identifies the content as mp4, and demuxes it.  It discovers it has video content that matches pads for `videomixer` and makes the connection to the first open pad.

So what you probably need to do is listen for the pad-added event on decodebin, check that it's the right pad, and then make your binding.

```
def decodebin_pad_added(self, decodebin, pad):
  #return if pad is wrong type

  #make the binding to the pad

decodebin.connect("pad_added", decodebin_pad_added)
```

You can see know that this behavior will be present by running `gst-inspect-1.0` on the element in question and examining the pads.  You can see that decodebin has a "sometimes" pad template vs. a constant pad that's present on subparse:

```
subparse:
Pads:
...
  SRC: 'src'
    Implementation:
      Has custom eventfunc(): gst_sub_parse_src_event
      Has custom queryfunc(): gst_sub_parse_src_query
      Has custom iterintlinkfunc(): gst_pad_iterate_internal_links_default
    Pad Template: 'src'

decodebin:
Pad Templates:
  SRC template: 'src_%u'
    Availability: Sometimes
    Capabilities:
      ANY
```

Comment: Thank you @mpr!  I'm going to try that, then I'll get back to you.

Comment: gst-inspect decodebin shows all sorts of useful goodness, such as the pad-added signal.  But what version of gst-plugins-base do you have.  My version does not show "custom eventfunc()" for the subparse.src pad.  I'm using version 1.8.1 of the plugins.

Comment: I'm on 1.6.  I'm not sure that you need to worry about those custom funcs, think they're just informational.

Comment: I want to connect my control source to the videomixer sink that receives the rendered subtitle text.  I set a listener for pad-added on videomixer, but the listener only gets called once and pad.get_name() ==> 'sink_0'.   But there should be a second sink, 'sink_1'.  Am I missing something else?

Comment: I'd guess you're not getting the `pad-added` event for sink_1 because you're adding the event listener after the pipeline parses and connects what it can.  For that one, maybe you can just get it by name using `gst_element_get_static_pad()`.

Comment: I just created a gist that shows my debug output from a pipeline test: https://gist.github.com/lsiden/48b0b05370fb43e7f43f9bee08265d32.  It's now sending the rendered text to videomixer.sink_0 which is a static pad.  sink_1 gets connected to the decoded video stream after the pipeline has started.  So it should work now, but isn't.

Comment: So you are saying it all connects but then when you change the values in the sliders it does nothing?

Comment: That's what it looks like.  I just added " video/x-raw,height-540 ! mixer..." before each of the mixer sinks.  Now both pads are available at startup.  The subtitles are connected to videomixer.sink_1 again.  Still no fade effect.  I was afraid that the timestamps might be wrong, but i verified that they are in nanosec (10^9) and match the subtitle timestamps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138271/discussion-between-mpr-and-lawrence-i-siden).

Comment: If you're still interested, I just updated https://gist.github.com/lsiden/48b0b05370fb43e7f43f9bee08265d32 with my latest debug output.